# Applescript to duplicate and rename

Tags: duplicates, applescript, rename

I'm attempting to create an AppleScript to duplicate a single file into a new location while renaming the file. I am getting hung up on the renaming of the file.

I've tried setting "with properties", setting aliases, and I still get errors.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please Enter Crate Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
    set loc to alias "Volumes:MusicExt:_Serato_:Subcrates:"
    set templatefile to alias "Volumes:MusicExt:Serato_Working:crate-template.crate"

    duplicate file templatefile to loc --> with properies {name:JobName}
    duplicate file templatefile to loc --> with properies {name:"10. Pre-CMY.m3u"}
 end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all HFS paths start always with a disk name and never with `Volumes`.
- Second of all never put the `file` keyword in front of an `alias` specifier

With the Finder you need two steps: Duplicate the file and then rename it.
Take advantage of the return value of `duplicate` which is the duplicated file.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please Enter Crate Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
    -- In this case just HFS string paths are preferable
    set loc to "MusicExt:_Serato_:Subcrates:"
    set templatefile to "MusicExt:Serato_Working:crate-template.crate"

    set duplicatedFile to duplicate file templatefile to folder loc
    set name of duplicatedFile to JobName -- (& ".crate") is there no file extension??
 end tell
```

Note: `with properties` works only with the `make` command.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. As an aside, the file extension is .crate in this instance.

Comment: Then you have to uncomment the code in parentheses `... to JobName & ".crate"` to add the file extension.